# About the advantages of the propensity perspective on probability

Tags: philosophy-of-science, metaphysics, philosophy-of-physics, probability, quantum-interpretations

I am wandering what are the advantages of the propensity perspective on probability. Why would it be better to explain probability in physics? Except for the fact that it solves various problems of frequentism (single case probability ect.), why would it be more preferable to define probability i.e. in Quantum Mechanics than the subjectivist account and frequentism? What is the modal element in the propensity view?

Comment: [SEP's Propensity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/probability-interpret/#ProInt) describes some of the motivations of the thinkers who favored propensities.